# How do you change the text of a label in Xcode by pressing two buttons?

Tags: swift

I understand how to change the text of a label by pressing one button. But what I want is to only be able to change the text after pressing two buttons. I have a table with names(all buttons) on the left column and specific stats on the top row(all buttons as well) to keep stats. I want to be able to press the name of a person and certain stats to change that corresponding label.

Comment: Keep track of the button states (pressed or not). When one button is pressed check the state of the other. Also, you're going to have this question closed as too broad.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code that you can provide to show an attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: how do you keep track of what is pressed? what is the specific action? @Shades

Comment: Hey OP, please consider marking my answer as 'accepted' if it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*[I know, the code below is very basic, but I think keeping it as simple as possible helps beginners understanding the basic concepts.]*

Create trackers for both buttons that keep track of whether the button has been pressed:

```
var pressedB1: Bool = false
var pressedB2: Bool = false
```

Check for the trackers' states in the buttons' actions:

```
@objc func pressedButton1(button: UIButton) {
    pressedB1 = true
    if pressedB2 {
        //change label's text
    }
}
```

...and the same for the other button.

Improving this code, you could use the buttons' tags, a single function for the buttons' actions, etc.. You could also use the buttons' control states which would also work better UX-wise.

Comment: Thanks @LinusGeffarth that worked!

Comment: You can use button tags also to keep track of which button is which.

Comment: Hey @TarvoMäesepp, I put exactly that suggestion at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: There is no need to use the tags of the buttons if you have references to them already.

Comment: You could use the tags and set them to `0` or `1` for whether they have been pressed already, @Abizern

Comment: Tags aren't really a good place to store state, particularly with numbers of 0 and 1. _hint_ what's the default value of a UIView's tag?

Comment: Right, you could add a custom property to `UIButton`. I'm guessing though that OP's project isn't very big and if OP were to re-use `.tag` for another purpose, OP'd figure out a way. As I stated: keeping it simple.